# Percentage padding not working on floated list items

Tags: css

I've created a standard menu - html looks like this:

```
                  <div>
                        <ul id="main-nav" class="clearfix">
                            <li><a id="Content_HyperLinkNav1">Compare</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Content_HyperLinkNav2" class="best-buy">Best Buys</a></li>
                            <li><a id="Content_HyperLinkNav3">Filter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

The menu renders left to right so the LI are set to float and a clearfix is applied to the parent UL.

I can add fixed padding to the link element but I wanted to make this dependent on the overall width of the LI (which contains the A).

Amongst many variations, I tried the following on the A element:

```
padding:0 5%;
```

But this doesn't apply 5% of the parent width - any ideas?

Here's the css I'm trying to work with:

```
 #main-nav
 {
     float:left;
     height:4.6rem;
     width:100%;
 }

 #main-nav li
 {
    float:left;
 }

 #main-nav li a
 {
    display:block;
    line-height:4.6rem;
    padding:0 2rem; /* this needs to be a percentage */
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the full css or a fiddle

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS alone because information about the child element's content will not filter back up to the parent element in such a way so that a CSS style can compute a value to affect a style.  You could do this with a JavaScript assisted solution.  Please restate your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A percentage value on top/bottom/right/left `padding` is relative to the width of the containing block.

When you say `5%`, you should ask yourself `5%` of what? As the containing block of `<a>` element - the list item in this case - doesn't have an explicit `width`, `5%` of `auto` would be `auto` which means nothing.

This is not ideal, but in this particular instance which `<li>` elements have `width`s of `auto`, assuming the `#main-nav` is as wide as the screen (the viewport), you could use **[viewport percentage unit `vw`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)** to specify the padding of descended `<a>`s with the respect to the width of the viewport.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/sateyu/2/edit)**

```css
#main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5vw; /* 1vw equals to  1/100 of the width of the viewport */
}
```

---

Otherwise, you probably need to apply the padding to `<li>` elements instead.

**[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/sateyu/3/edit)**

```css
#main-nav li {
  float:left;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, 5% of the viewport is the same as 2rem - fixed for each menu item, which is the same result as 2rem.

Comment: @dotnetnoob `5% of the viewport is the same as 2rem` Where did you get it from? `rem` stands for `root-em` which is relative to the font-size of the root element. in HTML the root element is `<html>`. Most of web browsers set a `font-size` of `16px` to the `<html>`. Therefore `2rem` would be `32px` which is completely different than `vw` unit. As a "proof" resize the output panel in the demo to see the effect of `vw` unit, each items would become wider/narrower during resizing.

Comment: I was speaking fuguratively. 5% of the viewport width is fixed for every menu item - I wanted to set a variable % based on the width of the LI. 2rem isn't necessarily the same width as 5vw but it results in the same fixed padding.

Comment: @dotnetnoob Seems I've misunderstood the question. Just noticed this part: `the overall width of the LI`. Okay then, if you want to specify the padding relative to the width of each individual `<li>` you have to specify the `width` of list items explicitly and the first part of my answer is still correct. But if you meant the overall width of existing `<li>`s (which are three in this case), I'm afraid that it's not possible to achieve that with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set width for `#main-nav`. E.g.

```
#main-nav { width: 60%; }
```

This is just an example. You can set any width in any unit. But set the width which will fit the inner contents.

Comment: I just set it to 100% but still no luck.

Comment: I have used below CSS and it's working fine 

                '.clearfix {
   clear: both;
  }
  li {
   float:left;
   padding: 0 5%;
  }'

Comment: Yesm you added the padding to LI - that does work but it doesn't work on the A

Comment: can you send me your exact CSS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer I wanted isn't possible after all. There are however other solutions that work differentlt to my requirements, but these might prove useful for anyone looking for similar functionality.